# In PIXI.js how can I increase the brightness of a sprite?

Tags: pixi.js

I have a sprite created through `new PIXI.Sprite.fromImage(path)`, how can I increase the brightness of it in realtime?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this using the [PIXI ColorMatrixFilter](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.filters.ColorMatrixFilter.html):

```
var colorMatrix =  [
    1,0,0,0,
    0,1,0,0,
    0,0,1,0,
    0,0,0,1
];
var filter = new PIXI.ColorMatrixFilter();
filter.matrix = colorMatrix;
stage.filters = [filter];
```

Darker:

```
var colorMatrix =  [
    1,0,0,-0.5,
    0,1,0,-0.5,
    0,0,1,-0.5,
    0,0,0,1
];
```

Lighter:

```
var colorMatrix =  [
    1,0,0,0.5,
    0,1,0,0.5,
    0,0,1,0.5,
    0,0,0,1
];
```

See a quick demo here: http://codepen.io/ianmcgregor/pen/LcjBw

Comment: Where did you learn this?  Is this just folklore or is there a tutorial out there that I haven't seen?

Comment: Just used PIXI a bunch! The PIXI filter system seems to be closely modelled on the ActionScript one, so old Flash tutorials might be relevant e.g.: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/04/28/understanding-as3-colormatrixfilter-class/

Comment: The demo no longer works. :( It looks like your example applies the filter to the stage, but what about applying it just to the sprite?

Comment: @imcg Can you please update your codeopen link. It is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

**PixiJS API Documentation: [PIXI.filters.ColorMatrixFilter](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.filters.ColorMatrixFilter.html)**

```
let filter = new PIXI.filters.ColorMatrixFilter();

// Darken
filter.matrix = [ 
    1, 0, 0, 0, -0.25, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, -0.25, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, -0.25, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0
]; 

// Lighten
filter.matrix = [ 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0.25, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0.25, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0
];

container.filters = [filter];
```